# Why I can't put my DDR2 RAM side by side?

Tags: installation, memory

1. I have been trying to put my RAMs side-by-side, but my PC won't boot.
2. I put the RAM only in slot A and my PC suddenly shutdown after about 24 hours.
3. I also tried put the RAM only in slot B, but the PC won't boot quite a few times and afterwards it boot. My PC hangs after a few seconds finish loading the windows.
4. Is my mobo slot damaged or my mobo is starting to die?

Specs:

- ASUS M3A78 Pro motherboard
- Corsair gaming RAM, 2GB each
- AMD PHENOM II X4 955
- NVIDIA GTX 460
- PSU GX 550W

Comment: Could you tell us your motherboard and what RAM your putting in? The CPU and GPU are a bit useless in solving this from what I know

Comment: my mobo is ASUS M3A78 Pro
my rams is corsair gaming memory 2gig each

Comment: sorry i just a beginner about pc hardware...

Comment: "corsair gaming memory" is also very generic, do you have a more exact model?

Comment: Sounds like a pin contact problem. Use a small paint brush or bulb syringe to clean the DIMM slots and then use an eraser to clean the contact pins on your RAM.

Then get a bootable CD with memory testing software (like most Linux LiveCDs) to test your memory.

If you have handled them with much static electricity on you before, they may have already been damaged.

Comment: DDR2 Corsair Gaming Memory 2GB 800Mhz (CGM2X2G800)..... okay i will try the method billc .... is there any possibility that my mobo slot damage? ... because when i run memtest there is no error...

Answer (score 3):

First things first. The [manual](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2Plus/M3A78_PRO/#download) mentions how the DIMMs need to be populated in Single/Dual channel mode. There's also a QVL (Qualified Vendor List) check your exact memory model/part number in that list.

[image: Memory Configuration]

Comment: to tell the truth... i dont know anything about that....

Comment: adding, sometimes going Dual channel , the memory can get more pickey, and sometimes adjusting the timing can "fix" that.  doing some memory testing and tweaking might be in order, especially if its not on the almighty compatability list :-)

Comment: okay... so how to tweak it?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings for memory timings and voltages. Try with all memory settings at defaults first.

Comment: It sounds like that level of stuff may be over his head.

Comment: @DarkPrince  you find pictures like this http://www.hardwareheaven.com/reviews/681/pg3/amd-athlon-7750-black-edition-and-asus-m3a78-t-asus-m3a78-t.html  See the bios pics.  And Get "tweaking guides" like this . http://gskill.us/forum/showthread.php?t=1276  (not to overclock but to learn)  Then you INCREASE the timing numbers decrease the speed, before putting in the memory, and mess with the numbers till it breaks again :-)   Then you use Memtest86 on a usb boot disk, to test it all.  it can take about 1/2 of a day, even if your clutzing around at first.

Comment: actually Synetech is right... this kind of technique level is to high for me.... sorry psycogeek .... i will just try rubbing and cleaning the slot only... if still something wrong i will seek someone expert to repair for me... thanks all for the help....

Answer (score 1):

If it were a “normal” problem like incompatibilities or incorrect configuration, then the erroneous results would be more consistent than what you described. Also, you said that a mem-test gave you no errors (how long/how many passes did you do), so chances are that nothing is damaged if it does indeed work. From the description you gave, I agree with billc.cn; it does sound like a contact problem which would give the intermittent (ie random) errors you are getting.

What I would recommend is to shut everything down and pull the plug (don’t just turn it off), then use a standard pencil eraser (not a hard one) to wipe off the pins on both sides of the RAM modules (and of course wipe off the rubber shavings). Next, use an old toothbrush to lightly brush the RAM slots (perhaps breathing onto them to add a slight bit of humidity).

If that does not do the trick, examine the pins on the RAM sticks. Do they look clean and shiny? If not, try repeating the cleaning. (I have in the past even resorted to using an [emory board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLx4U.jpg)/cardboard nail file—to lightly scrub the pins on the sticks and in the slots.)

Comment: okay i will try it....